# What should I do if the answer I needed is contained in one of the answers but mixed up with counterproductive advice?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, etiquette, self-answer

After posting [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814217/how-to-make-a-tkinter-button-change-its-own-text-attribute/67823348), I obtained the information I needed mostly by reading the comments. One person posted an answer that basically contains all the information I needed to solve the issue, but in a way I find confusing.

My idea was to simply add an answer that shows only the useful piece of information from everything I read, but people seem to react badly to that. What should I do?

Answer (score 38):

There's nothing wrong with adding your own answer, so long as it doesn't duplicate existing answers. If another answer basically has the solution, but has a lot of additional fluff, or is presented in a confusing manner, you're actually providing value if you add an answer that's simpler, or clearer. Don't focus on the fact that the other answer is confusing to you, unless it has actively misleading advice that should be called out.

Make sure to attribute the other answer if it was helpful in writing your own answer. Something like this should work:

> This is based on Other User's answer ... [followed by the solution in your own words], [and additional information as relevant]

Note that you must link directly to the other answer (this is required by the license for all content on Stack Overflow). Generally, just make the text "Other User's answer" into a link to that answer. You can obtain a permalink to any post by clicking the "share" link below it, on the far left-hand side.

If some comments helped you form your answer, there's no harm in giving them credit as well, though comments are ephemeral, and may not last long. If you choose to attribute comments, you're better off quoting the comments directly:

> As mentioned by Yet Another User
>
> > [whatever they said]

You can also include a link to the comment, if you choose. You can obtain a permalink to a comment by clicking on its timestamp.

Again, keep in mind that you should only add an answer if it adds value; i.e., you feel that the answer covers ground that is not covered in other answers and/or presents the material in a clearer fashion.

Comment: In addition to this, I prefer to make the answer community-wiki if I feel like I don't add (a lot) of information myself, but just summarise/collect info from comments and answers.

Comment: This is a great answer and I hope it turns into a FAQ entry somewhere

Comment: @DanielWiddis It mostly already is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Why clarifying the already posted answer a possible path?

Answer (score 10):

You can ask the answerer to edit their answer to rearrange it, and explain why—the additional information you didn't need could be useful to other users. Or you could do the rearrangement and put an explanation in the edit comment box, and perhaps the answerer will accept that edit quickly or make an improvement to it.

Comment: Having edited an answer and been chastised by the original answerer for that, I would strongly echo the sequence of asking the answerer *First*.

Comment: @DanielWiddis bah, if they don't want their content edited, [maybe they should use other site](/help/editing): *If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*

Comment: @Braiam tell that to Jon Skeet.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I haven't been able to have a constructive edit in a Jon Skeet post.

Comment: @Braiam Constructive is a subjective term. I thought I was making a constructive edit, but Mr. Skeet disagreed.

Answer (score -20):

Edit the answer to be sufficiently clear and useful. While you edit, keep in mind:

- Make a sufficient change (which in this case you probably will)
- Fix *all* of the problems in the post
- Don't change the answer so much that it distracts from the original intent of the post

If you satisfy all of these criteria, suggest your edit, and it will probably be approved.

Comment: In this case I am not sure I agree with the original intent of the post, so I'd have to distract from it. (It contains the info but they are not presented as the answer to my problem)

Comment: Try submitting an edit anyway, if that gets rejected it's probably a good idea to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't submit an edit that changes the author's intent ever. This is true even if you have full editing privileges. Downvote if the answer is not useful and/or write a separate answer in that case. Edits should only be made to clean up posts, clarify wording, etc, and *never* to change the intent.

Comment: @cigien What if you're unsure?

Comment: You can ask the OP for clarification. OP may edit the answer themsleves, or if they confirm that your suggestion is fine, then making the edit is ok. If in doubt, avoid making the edit.

Comment: @cigien Not if they don't submit the edit in the first place, as you suggested...

Comment: I meant that you should ask for clarification in the comments. I know it can be hard to communicate what edits you'd like to make in that fashion, but note that if you suggest an edit, and the OP doesn't see it, it gets sent to the review queue, where it's likely to get rejected if it's a substantial change, or changes the intent. It also creates additional work for other users, which is avoidable. If you have full edit privileges, you *could* edit anyway, but then leave a comment telling the author what you were trying to do, and mention that they should rollback if they don't approve.

Comment: @cigien: It's a judgement call sometimes.  If an answer proposed useful actual code, but then cites some incorrect reasons why it's a good approach, IMO it's ok to fact-check the justification.  Their intent was to justify why this code / piece of advice is good in terms of (for example) how CPU architecture and/or compilers work.  Not specifically to mislead readers about how CPUs work / why something is a good idea.  Of course, if they've built too much explanation on a totally false premise, there's sometimes no saving it, and rewriting whole paragraphs is usually too big an edit.

Comment: ... unless (as you say) you get permission in comments from the author.  I've done that a few times, where I commented but they weren't understanding what I was trying to explain in comments.  So I just fixed / rewrote some parts of the answer, and left a comment.  Pretty much every time, such edits have been appreciated, often with the user thanking me for improving their own understanding of the subject.  Even if you don't have 2k rep edit privileges, if you submit an edit while the other user is active (after they reply to a comment), they can see your edit and approve (or not) before the Q

Comment: If an answer has unclear or dubious content, request clarification in a comment. That's one of the main reasons that comments exist!

Comment: @PM2Ring The OP understands the answer, but feels that others might not, so the OP has all of the clarification they need already...

Comment: @Anonymous Anne found the answer helpful but confusing. So she should use comments to encourage the author to eliminate that confusion. If she edits the answer, not only does she change the post from the author's original intent, there's the risk that she could introduce incorrect information. Instead, she has written her own answer, in her own words, using the information she has distilled from that other answer, and if there are any errors or lack of clarity in *her* answer then people can point them out in comments.

Comment: @PM2Ring how can an answer be helpful and confusing. It's not helpful if you are confused by it, no?

Comment: @Braiam It would be more helpful if it were less confusing.

Comment: @PM2Ring it's helpful or confusing, both characteristics are orthogonal.

Comment: @Braiam The OP said "answer [...] basically contains all the information I needed to solve the issue, but in a way I find confusing". So the answer helped them, "but [it was] mixed up with counterproductive advice". So they want to present the useful info they were able to extract, and present it in a less confusing fashion.

Comment: @Braiam FWIW, I often find your posts helpful. However, I sometimes find your posts difficult to understand, and sometimes I just skip them because I can't figure out what you're trying to say or imply. Perhaps it's a language barrier issue. I'm not saying that you have poor English skills, but you have a tendency to use English in a way that seems alien to me (a native speaker of 50+ years experience).